# sort by new in magento 1.7.0.2 ce as default for category page

Tags: category, product-list, magento-1, product-collection, sorting

We can't manage to sort by new as default in the category product list.

This does only work when we set the order option in the category back-end, but due to our large category three we can't do this manually for every category and subcategory.

Is there anyway to specify a the default sort order on categories?

Answer (score 2):

You can change this setting directly in the database, but this is always a bad idea, but if you only want to change it once, I would do it this way.

**BE CAREFUL. MAKE BACKUP. BEST WISHES!**

1. check in `eav_attribute` for the `attribute_id` of the `default_sort_by` category attribute. Category attributes have normally the `entity_type_id` `3`, but you can check this in `eav_entity_type`
2. Check in `catalog_category_entity_varchar` for the new value in an already changed category.
3. `UPDATE catalog_category_entity_varchar SET value = '<your value>' WHERE attribute_id = <your attribute id>;`